# Web.config file debug="true" setting

Tags: asp.net

I have run into an issue that when my web application's web.config compilation debug is set to true I am getting a vulnerability error on a security scan.

What I want to determine is if there is a way to have some type of web.config conditional block change the debug setting to use the correct value on debug builds and release builds. I have read that setting the property in each web page itself will do this and don't know if this is in fact true and are there any problems with this?

Comment: are you sure that you using ASP Classic? I suppose you are using ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `<deployment retail=”true”/>`.

You put [this element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228298%28VS.80%29.aspx) into your [machine.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on the production server and it overrides `debug=”true”` in your web.config and pages. In other words, you can happily use the debug and trace functionality on your developer machines but can be sure it is turned off on the production server. Scott Guthrie [recommends](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled) this as best practice.

Comment: I read the article; however, my website is published and there is only one configuration web.config file. I do not not have either the web.release.config or web.debug.config files.

Comment: Are you developing on a different machine to the machine on which you deploy? On the web server, do you have access to machine.config (likely 'no' if shared hosting)? If either of those are 'no' then my suggestion won't help. If yes to both, what I'm saying is, put 'deployment retail=”true”' into machine.config and put 'debug=true' into web.config whenever you like as it will make no difference on the live server.